# Creating Record for Many to Many Model EmberJS 2.6

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have two models. Lets call them `mult` and `post`. They have a many to many relationship.

Their definitions looks like:

Post:

```
export default Model.extend({
  name: attr(),
  mult: hasMany('mult')
});
```

Mult:

```
export default Model.extend({
  name: attr(),
  perspectives: hasMany('post')
});
```

I want to start off by creating a `Post` and adding `Mults` to it. So, I do

```
createPost(name) {
  let post = this.get('store').createRecord('post', {
    name: name, mults: []
  });
  post.save();
},
```

in my controller.js. However, this then throws an exception of

```
mult.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _emberData.default) is not a function
```

and it is referring to this line of `mult`:

`name: (0, _emberData['default'])(),`

Can I create a `post` first without providing any `mults`? If so, what might be a suggested workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You can't set hasMany relations on createRecord. Confusing, I know, but first create the record then set the muts.